# my application fall as i open the fourth activitity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I've tried to solve it by myself but I got crazy for I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I develop a very simple application that the user needs to answer to about 10 questions and the program takes the input to calculate it and return recommended by his input.

it's passed from one activity to another (the answer save in the XML's files) and the fourth activity converts all the answers to java and in this java file, I do the calculation.

but when I pass from activity to another everything works fine until the last activity that crosses any time I even don't start to calculate. 
in the converting step, I did the emulator and any time its fall. 
I tried to delete the RadioButton convert and it works fine but I convert the RadioButton good as far as I know.

my javaFile code (last activity):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);


        //declare RadioGroup
        sort_b_r_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sort_b_r_g);
        winter_r_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.winter_r_g);
        stand_r_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.stand_r_g);
        corner_r_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.corner_r_g);
        sex_r_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sex_r_g);

        //declare RadioButton.... the problem is here.

        sort_b_r_b=(RadioButton) findViewById(sort_b_r_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        winter_r_b=(RadioButton) findViewById(winter_r_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        stand_r_b=(RadioButton) findViewById(stand_r_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        corner_r_b=(RadioButton) findViewById(corner_r_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        sex_r_b=(RadioButton) findViewById(sex_r_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

}
}
```

thanks very much for the helper:)!

with regard to the responder, the application just fall.
the error:
"ApplicatioName has stopped.
the open app again"

the logcat error:

```
01-05 07:47:42.389 5213-5213/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-05 07:47:42.425 5213-5213/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-05 07:47:42.840 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-05 07:47:43.572 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline

                                                                             [ 01-05 07:47:43.641  5213: 5239 D/         ]
                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x966c00c0, tid 5239
01-05 07:47:43.650 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
01-05 07:47:43.650 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-05 07:47:43.650 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-05 07:47:43.651 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-05 07:47:43.651 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
01-05 07:47:43.666 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa9d852a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
01-05 07:47:43.704 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:43.847 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:49.596 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
01-05 07:47:49.600 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
01-05 07:47:49.600 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
01-05 07:47:49.722 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=51KB
01-05 07:47:49.723 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=51KB
01-05 07:47:49.723 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
01-05 07:47:49.723 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-05 07:47:49.723 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
01-05 07:47:49.797 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:49.812 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:49.832 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=110KB, data=63KB
01-05 07:47:49.832 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=91KB, data=44KB
01-05 07:47:50.062 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:50.159 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:50.236 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:47:50.316 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity V/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring 0 children of 1073741851
01-05 07:47:50.329 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 8332 bytes, containing 1 windows, 29 views
01-05 07:47:53.936 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=78KB
01-05 07:47:53.940 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=78KB
01-05 07:47:53.940 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
01-05 07:48:03.404 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=248KB, data=171KB
01-05 07:48:03.413 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=245KB, data=131KB
01-05 07:48:03.517 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:48:03.575 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:48:03.685 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:48:03.742 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:48:03.787 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity V/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring 0 children of 1073741840
01-05 07:48:03.793 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 5020 bytes, containing 1 windows, 18 views
01-05 07:48:03.829 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:48:04.169 5213-5239/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9d852a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9d83280)
01-05 07:48:04.893 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=247KB, data=147KB
01-05 07:48:04.893 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=247KB, data=147KB
01-05 07:48:04.893 5213-5218/com.example.yagel.twoactivity I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
01-05 07:48:26.207 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-05 07:48:26.208 5213-5213/com.example.yagel.twoactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.yagel.twoactivity, PID: 5213
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yagel.twoactivity/com.example.yagel.twoactivity.Last}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.yagel.twoactivity.Last.onCreate(Last.java:42)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yagel.twoactivity.Last">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/soft_im"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/soft" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/long_im"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/long_b" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fish_im"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fish" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/short_im"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/short_b" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ans"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:text="כנראה שלא מלאת את כל הפרטים.\nיש לחזור על התהליך ולמלא את כל הפרטים"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**edit after found solution**
ok, so I found out my problem parentally the R.id.id_name is become a null anytime the app intent to another project.

so, when I tried to give order about some variable at the second activity (from the fourth) the app got a null from it.

so the solution is by making variable "public static" that represent the information in the R.id.id_name (for example I had TextView "id_name", so in the second activity I initialize String name_s and did name_s＝id_name.gettext() then the variable didn't change when opening new activity..)

the app works well, if you have another technic better then mine I will be happy to hear it thanks very much to the helper:)

Comment: what error message(s) do you get?

Comment: please post your logcat errors

Comment: Post Logcat and your XML layout code.

Comment: I added at the last line the image of the error

Comment: Post `logcat` and `run` there is where you can you cause of force close

Comment: when I find the logic output?

Comment: I added the logcat error.

Comment: One of your `RadioGroup` variables is null, maybe because it has another ID in the layout file. To find out which one look in line 42 of Last.java

Comment: I was looking at line 42 and all other RadioGroup and none of them is null... I search for duplexity at the layout file and nothing.. maybe you have other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It's just another NullPointerException. You use getCheckedRadioButtonId() on a null. Fix it and it will work. Log your code and check, why your radio button is null.

Comment: sorry but I tried to find that RadioGroup that is null and didn't found.
I even did a if(RadioGroupx==null) Toast... "radioGroupx is null"
but it still fall in the excuse that NullPointerException...
someone? help...

Comment: You can upload your project, I'll download it and try to fix it